# Android Suffle ArrayList of Bitmap keeping the original positions

Tags: android, list, random, arraylist, shuffle

i am trying to write a code which suffles an Array of Bitmap but i'd like to keep in another array the positions where the Bitmaps are moved to. In order to do that, i am doing as follows:

```
int[] ar = {  1,  2, 3, 7, 12,  4,  5, 13, 8, 9, 11, 10,  6 , 14, 15};
public static ArrayList<Bitmap> shuffleArray(int[] ar, ArrayList<Bitmap> arraybmorig)
{
  Bitmap[] arraybmfinal = new Bitmap[arraybmorig.size()];

  for (int i=0; i<ar.length; i++)
  {

    arraybmfinal[ar[i]] = arraybmorig.get(i); 
  }

  return new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arraybmfinal));
}
```

But my code is not efficient and i'd like to random my fixed array ar[]... What is the best way to do this features ?

Thx in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you wanna shuffle your `ar` array and than put bitmaps in `ar` position.
You have at least two ways to shuffle array:

```
private void ShuffleArray(int[] array)
{
    int index, temp;
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
        index = random.nextInt(i + 1);
        temp = array[index];
        array[index] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

and second way - use default method for ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i=1;i<=add.length();i++){
   x.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(x);
```

Comment: Really what i want shuffle is the  ArrayList<Bitmap> arraybmorig, my arr[] is only a way to mark the positions where the items of the Array should go...

Comment: Sorry but your first code simply shuffles the array of int[], and the second one with Collections you do not know where the items were to...

Comment: Yes. And after shuffles of the array of int[], put your bitmaps in positions ar[0], ar[1] , etc

Comment: Ok, your first way is useful to generate new random positions for ar[]